# Change second and third html input while html input 1 is being written

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am showing the values of a database table in a html + php table and my goal is to change the input of the quantity or price of an article and automatically change the total value up to the number of the line being edited and update the remaining rows with the value that was entered in that total.

I think this can be used with javascript or whatever but I don't know js, I hope someone can help me.

```
<tbody>
<?php
$sql=sprintf("SELECT * FROM rostosativos_invoiceprop WHERE id_proposta = '".$_GET['id']."'");
$res=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ ?>
<tr>                                                                
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['produto']; ?>" name="product"></td>         
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['precouni']; ?>" name="priceunit"></td>                                                              
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['quantidade']; ?>" name="quantity"></td>                                                              
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['soma']; ?>" name="sum"></td>                                                                 
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $r['totalsoma']; ?>" name="totalsum"></td>                                                                                                                           
   <td class="actions">
      <a href="maisproposta?id=<?php echo $r['id_proposta']; ?>" class="delete-row"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>                                                
   </td>                                                        </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Example:

3 lines on the table

name   | priceunit | quantity | sum | totalsum

product 1 | 5.00 | 2 | 10.00 | 10.00
product 2 | 5.00 | 1 | 5.00  | 15.00
product 3 | 2.00 | 2 | 4.00  | 19.00

I change product 2 price

I want it to do this automatically

name   | priceunit | quantity | sum | totalsum

product 1 | 5.00  | 2 | 10.00  | 10.00
product 2 | 10.00 | 1 | 10.00  | 20.00
product 3 | 2.00  | 2 | 4.00   | 24.00

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Dharman what should I change ??

Comment: Don't concatenate variables/data into SQL statement. Read the links, please.

Comment: @Dharman Hm ok I'm changing my queries now, but just one thing how can I check my queries ? example (when i'm inserting values on db and it fails I echo the sprintf line and I can see whats missing, how can I do that in this method?)

Comment: better how can I use ``` if (mysqli_query($link,$sql)) ``` for alerts ?

Comment: You can still echo out the result of sprintf if you want, but it would be more sensible to either use a debugger or `var_dump` the values separately.

Comment: If you get stuck when creating prepared statements, then open new question. I think we better not pollute this one with off-topic discussions.

Comment: I'm not a Expert, I had this code  "sprintf(insert...)" and now I changed to $sql -> prepare("insert...") with $sql -> bind_param(...) I cannot echo that I think

Comment: Yes, correct, but why would you want to echo it? Echo the data only.

Comment: Ok I got it but how am I going to do the alert thing now ? with the if statement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before applying jquery or javascript, need to place .class/#id for each input. In this case for price, quantity, sum & totalSum. So a single row will be like this

```
<tr>                                                                
   <td><input type="text" value="1" name="product"></td>         
   <td><input type="text" class="price" value="5.00" name="priceunit"></td>                                                              
   <td><input type="text" class="qty" value="2" name="quantity"></td>                                                              
   <td><input type="text" class="sum" value="10.00" name="sum"></td>                                                                 
   <td><input type="text" class="totalSum" value="10.00" name="totalsum"></td>                                                                                                                           
   <td class="actions">
      <a href="maisproposta?id=1" class="delete-row"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>                                                
   </td>
```

The jquery can be apply by a method looping every time to remove the calculation bugs.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nishalkr93/xgzj6smb/7/)

```
$(document).on('keyup','.qty, .price',function(e){
        findTotal();
});

 function findTotal(){
    var totalSum = 0;
    var price,qty,sum;

  $rows = $('#productPriceList tbody tr');
    $.each($rows,function(key,row){
        price = Number($(row).find('.price').val());
        qty = Number($(row).find('.qty').val());

        sum =  price * qty;
    totalSum += sum;

    $(row).find('.sum').val(sum.toFixed(2)); 
        $(row).find('.totalSum').val(totalSum.toFixed(2)); 
    });
 }
```

Comment: Where should I put that code ?  I've put inside <script></script and it's not working

Comment: It's working now I just have to update on the database every value